# Zoom after search using autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, leaflet, geojson

How to do after a search, zoom in on the value found on the map? My code is:

```
$("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
    source: setoresComerciais.features.map(function(d){
        return d.properties.sco_num_sc + " - " + d.properties.sco_dsc_loc
    }),
    select: function(event, ui){
        map.fitBounds(stComerciaisLayer.getBounds(ui.item.value));
    } 
});
```

First, I get `return d.properties.sco_num_sc + " - " + d.properties.sco_dsc_loc`, this return, for example: `"1 - FORTALEZA"`
After, I use select, where have the param ui, when do `ui.item.value` return `"1 - FORTALEZA"`, so this:

```
map.fitBounds(stComerciaisLayer.getBounds(ui.item.value));
```

Where:

```
stComerciaisLayer = L.geoJSON(setoresComerciais, {
                style: function (feature) {
                    return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
                },
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
(...)
```

It was to return exactly what I wanted, the result of the search and the zoom in it, but don't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: i think you need latlng to zoomin or zoomout to that point like this 
map.setView([lat, lng], zoom);

also please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083285/leaflet-set-zoom-level-on-search

Comment: I tried, but don't work, I don't understand :'( and I thought that
 fitBounds already get the maximum zoom and the coordinates

Comment: I am confused, it offers Autocomplete as a feature. Are you using jQuery UI Autocomplete instead?

Comment: Yep, I'm using jquery UI Autocomplete because I need it. The autocomplete is working, the problem is with the zoom in locate :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
map.fitBounds(stComerciaisLayer.getBounds(ui.item.value));
```

won't work as intended. From the API documentation, getBounds() doesn't take any arguments, it just returns the bounds of they layer you are working with. As the layer includes all your geojson, this won't work.

Instead, we can get the selected feature's geojson from your geojson FeatureCollection, and from that make a layer (we don't need to add it to the map), so that we can find its bounds and update the map accordingly.

How do we get the proper feature in the geojson? There are a few approaches, we could use a dictionary, or we could add additional data to the autocomplete function source (as suggested in the other answer). I'll follow the lead in the other answer, but use the increment of the feature and continue to use .map() :

```
source: setoresComerciais.features.map(function(d,i){
    return {
      label: d.properties.sco_num_sc + " - " + d.properties.sco_dsc_loc, 
      id: i 
    };
```

Here .map takes two variables: `d` is the current item in the features array being processed, and `i` is the index of that feature. With the index, we can easily access the proper item in the features array, make a layer out of it, and fit the map bounds to that feature's layer:

```
select: function(event, ui){
    var feature = setoresComerciais.features[ui.item.id]; // get the geojson
    var featureLayer = L.geoJSON(feature)  // create a layer from it
    map.fitBounds(featureLayer.getBounds()); // resize the map
}
```

Altogether, that gives us:

```
    $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
        source: setoresComerciais.features.map(function(d,i){
            return {label: d.properties.sco_num_sc + " - " + d.properties.sco_dsc_loc, id: i };
        }),
        select: function(event, ui){
            var feature = setoresComerciais.features[ui.item.id];
            var featureLayer = L.geoJSON(feature)
            map.fitBounds(featureLayer.getBounds());
        } 
    });
```

Comment: Man...I love you, thanks!!! *-* My problem is: I still not understand functions and read docs, How would I know I would need to add an "i" in the parameters and an id inside the function? And other thing, about read docs, read them from beginning to end, but I find it difficult to understand :(

Comment: The names of the parameters in the function passed to .map() are arbitrary, their content is dictated by their order. I use d to represent datum and i to represent index, but you could use `function(el,id) { return { label: el.properties.sco_num_sc, id: id }` (it is common to see `el`, short for element). Not all parts are arbitrary though, the jquery-autocomplete function uses the label property to set the visible text - it expects this property to be present if it is given an array of objects, the property id is arbitrary: it is just a property to store the index for later

Answer (score 1):

Not used this plugin, but going to take a stab at it anyway.

I would advise that you make a more complex `source`, making use of the `source: function(request, response){}` feature. [See more](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

```
$("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
  source: function(req, resp){
    var results = [];
    $.each(setoresComerciais.features.properties, function(k, p){
      if(p.sco_dsc_loc.toLowerCase().indexOf(req.term.toLowerCase()) == 0){
        results.push({
          label: p.sco_num_sc + " - " + p.sco_dsc_loc,
          value: p.sco_dsc_loc,
          properties: p
        });
      }
    });
    resp(results);
  },
  select: function(event, ui){
    map.fitBounds(stComerciaisLayer.getBounds(ui.item.value));
    return false;
  } 
});
```

This will ensure that there is a `{ label, value }` pair for each potential result. You can also access all the `properties` too via `ui.item.properties` in select if you like.

This will also mean that you are passing just `"FORTALEZA"` and not `"1 - FORTALEZA"` which may confuse the plugin if it does match a title in the map data.

If you had provided example data or a jsFiddle, I would have tested this solution.

---

**Update**

Did some more reading. I see:

> `fitBounds(<LatLngBounds> bounds, <fitBounds options> options?)`
>
> Sets a map view that contains the given geographical bounds with the maximum zoom level possible.

```
map.fitBounds([
    [40.712, -74.227],
    [40.774, -74.125]
]);
```

To me, it appears the function is expecting a array versus a String. This is something that is returned by `.getBounds()`. Yet nothing I read advises that `.getBounds()` does not accept input. So I do not think `stComerciaisLayer.getBounds(ui.item.value)` will return the value you want.

---

**Note**

You've selected a great answer, and just updating my code as an alternative.

```
$("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
  source: function(req, resp){
    var results = [];
    $.each(setoresComerciais.features, function(k, f){
      var props = f.properties;
        if(props.sco_dsc_loc.toLowerCase().indexOf(req.term.toLowerCase()) == 0){
        results.push({
          label: props.sco_num_sc + " - " + props.sco_dsc_loc,
          value: props.sco_dsc_loc,
          properties: props,
          id: k
        });
      }
    });
    resp(results);
  },
  select: function(event, ui){
    var feature = setoresComerciais.features[ui.item.id];
    var featureLayer = L.geoJSON(feature)
    map.fitBounds(featureLayer.getBounds());
  } 
});
```